# R: LMM with covariate

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, linear

I know there have been a number of posts on lmer, but I am struggling to find my answer through research and am hoping to get your help.

I am analyzing data from a study with the following data:

1) **Score** = the DV, a participants score on a given test.

2) **Test** = IV, within-subjects variable. Tests were taken at 4 different time points--1 pre intervention and 3 post intervention tests. Not all participants completed all 4 tests.

3) **Group** = between-subjects variable, subjects were assigned to either an intervention or control group.

4) **Resistance** = a covariate that may explain why intervention was more/less effective in a given participant.

I want to know whether **Score** varies as a function of **Group** across tests. I'd also like to know whether **Resistance** modifies the change in test scores moreso for the intervention group than the control (so, a three way interaction, I think?).

Seriously, any help, advice, links to resources would be incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `lme4` syntax you could write the model as

`lmer(Score ~ Test + Group * Resistance + (Test | Subject))`

(Assuming of course that linear models' assumptions are not violated, and that the residuals of the model have are normally distributed.)

For more info on `lme4` syntax see Table 2 [here](http://www.gr.xemacs.org/mirrors/CRAN/web/packages/lme4/vignettes/lmer.pdf), or this well-done [blog post](https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I had seen the paper before, but had not seen the blog post yet.